# JMS using jboss

Tags: java, jboss, jms

I am new to JMS. When I am running standalone JMS test program, getting below exception

The Exception I'm getting is below:

```
**Channel end notification received, closing channel Channel ID 4995329b (inbound) of Remoting connection 0aff5851 to null**
```

I am attaching my code below for your reference:

**QueueReceiver.java**

```
package com.tradier.webservices.util;

    import java.util.Hashtable;

    import javax.jms.*;

    import javax.naming.Context;
    import javax.naming.InitialContext;
    import javax.naming.NamingException;
    public class QueueReceive {
    private final static String JNDI_FACTORY =
    "org.jboss.naming.remote.client.InitialContextFactory";//org.jboss.naming.remote.client.InitialContextFactory
    private final static String JMS_FACTORY = "java:jboss/exported/jms/RemoteConnectionFactory";
    private final static String QUEUE = "queue/test";
    private final static String jbossUrl = "remote://localhost:4447";

    private static InitialContext getInitialContext() throws NamingException {
    Hashtable env = new Hashtable();
    env.put(Context.INITIAL_CONTEXT_FACTORY, JNDI_FACTORY);
    env.put(Context.PROVIDER_URL, jbossUrl);
    env.put(Context.SECURITY_PRINCIPAL, "jms");
    env.put(Context.SECURITY_CREDENTIALS, "jboss1");
    return new InitialContext(env);
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
    InitialContext ic = getInitialContext();
    QueueConnectionFactory qconFactory = (QueueConnectionFactory)ic.lookup(JMS_FACTORY);
    QueueConnection qcon = qconFactory.createQueueConnection("jms","jboss1");
    QueueSession qsession = qcon.createQueueSession(false, Session.AUTO_ACKNOWLEDGE);
    Queue queue = (Queue)ic.lookup(QUEUE);
    QueueReceiver qreceiver = qsession.createReceiver(queue);

    qcon.start();

    TextMessage msg = (TextMessage)qreceiver.receive();
    System.out.println("MYTEXT"+msg.getText());

    qreceiver.close();
    qsession.close();
    qcon.close();
    }
    }
```

**QueueSender.java**

```
 package com.tradier.webservices.util;

    import java.util.Hashtable;
    import javax.jms.Queue;
    import javax.jms.QueueConnection;
    import javax.jms.QueueConnectionFactory;
    import javax.jms.QueueSender;
    import javax.jms.QueueSession;
    import javax.jms.Session;
    import javax.jms.TextMessage;

    import javax.naming.Context;
    import javax.naming.InitialContext;
    import javax.naming.NamingException;

    public class QueueSend {
    private final static String JNDI_FACTORY =
    "org.jboss.naming.remote.client.InitialContextFactory";
    private final static String JMS_FACTORY = "jms/RemoteConnectionFactory";
    private final static String QUEUE = "jms/queue/test";
    private final static String jbossUrl = "remote://localhost:4447";

    private static InitialContext getInitialContext() throws NamingException {
    Hashtable env = new Hashtable();
    env.put(Context.INITIAL_CONTEXT_FACTORY, JNDI_FACTORY);
    env.put(Context.PROVIDER_URL, jbossUrl);
    env.put(Context.SECURITY_PRINCIPAL, "qtest");
    env.put(Context.SECURITY_CREDENTIALS, "mytest");
    return new InitialContext(env);
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
    InitialContext ic = getInitialContext();
    try{
    QueueConnectionFactory qconFactory =
    (QueueConnectionFactory)ic.lookup(JMS_FACTORY);

    QueueConnection qcon =
    qconFactory.createQueueConnection("qtest","mytest");
    QueueSession qsession = qcon.createQueueSession(false,
    Session.AUTO_ACKNOWLEDGE);
    Queue queue = (Queue)ic.lookup(QUEUE);
    QueueSender qsender = qsession.createSender(queue);

    qcon.start();

    TextMessage msg = qsession.createTextMessage();;
    msg.setText("HelloWorld");
    qsender.send(msg);

    qsender.close();
    qsession.close();
    qcon.close();
    }
    catch(Exception e){
        System.out.println(e);
    }
    }
    }
```

**jboss standalone.xml file**

```
<subsystem xmlns="urn:jboss:domain:messaging:1.1">
                <hornetq-server>
                    <persistence-enabled>true</persistence-enabled>
                    <security-enabled>false</security-enabled>
                    <journal-file-size>102400</journal-file-size>
                    <journal-min-files>2</journal-min-files>

                    <connectors>
                        <netty-connector name="netty" socket-binding="messaging"/>
                        <netty-connector name="netty-throughput" socket-binding="messaging-throughput">
                            <param key="batch-delay" value="50"/>
                        </netty-connector>
                        <in-vm-connector name="in-vm" server-id="0"/>
                    </connectors>

                    <acceptors>
                        <netty-acceptor name="netty" socket-binding="messaging"/>
                        <netty-acceptor name="netty-throughput" socket-binding="messaging-throughput">
                            <param key="batch-delay" value="50"/>
                            <param key="direct-deliver" value="false"/>
                        </netty-acceptor>
                        <in-vm-acceptor name="in-vm" server-id="0"/>
                    </acceptors>

                    <broadcast-groups>
                        <broadcast-group name="bg-group1">
                            <group-address>231.7.7.7</group-address>
                            <group-port>9876</group-port>
                            <broadcast-period>5000</broadcast-period>
                            <connector-ref>
                                netty
                            </connector-ref>
                        </broadcast-group>
                    </broadcast-groups>

                    <discovery-groups>
                        <discovery-group name="dg-group1">
                            <group-address>231.7.7.7</group-address>
                            <group-port>9876</group-port>
                            <refresh-timeout>10000</refresh-timeout>
                        </discovery-group>
                    </discovery-groups>

                    <cluster-connections>
                        <cluster-connection name="my-cluster">
                            <address>jms</address>
                            <connector-ref>netty</connector-ref>
                            <discovery-group-ref discovery-group-name="dg-group1"/>
                        </cluster-connection>
                    </cluster-connections>

                    <security-settings>
                        <security-setting match="#">
                            <permission type="send" roles="guest"/>
                            <permission type="consume" roles="guest"/>
                            <permission type="createNonDurableQueue" roles="guest"/>
                            <permission type="deleteNonDurableQueue" roles="guest"/>
                        </security-setting>
                    </security-settings>

                    <address-settings>
                        <address-setting match="#">
                            <dead-letter-address>jms.queue.DLQ</dead-letter-address>
                            <expiry-address>jms.queue.ExpiryQueue</expiry-address>
                            <redelivery-delay>0</redelivery-delay>
                            <max-size-bytes>10485760</max-size-bytes>
                            <address-full-policy>BLOCK</address-full-policy>
                            <message-counter-history-day-limit>10</message-counter-history-day-limit>
                            <redistribution-delay>1000</redistribution-delay>
                        </address-setting>
                    </address-settings>

                    <jms-connection-factories>
                        <connection-factory name="InVmConnectionFactory">
                            <connectors>
                                <connector-ref connector-name="in-vm"/>
                            </connectors>
                            <entries>
                                <entry name="java:/ConnectionFactory"/>
                            </entries>
                        </connection-factory>
                        <connection-factory name="RemoteConnectionFactory">
                            <connectors>
                                <connector-ref connector-name="netty"/>
                            </connectors>
                            <entries>
                                <entry name="RemoteConnectionFactory"/>
                                <entry name="java:jboss/exported/jms/RemoteConnectionFactory"/>
                            </entries>
                        </connection-factory>
                        <pooled-connection-factory name="hornetq-ra">
                            <transaction mode="xa"/>
                            <connectors>
                                <connector-ref connector-name="in-vm"/>
                            </connectors>
                            <entries>
                                <entry name="java:/JmsXA"/>
                            </entries>
                        </pooled-connection-factory>
                    </jms-connection-factories>

                    <jms-destinations>
                        <jms-queue name="testQueue">
                            <entry name="queue/test"/>
                            <entry name="java:jboss/exported/jms/queue/test"/>
                        </jms-queue>
                    </jms-destinations>
                </hornetq-server>
            </subsystem>
```

Help me in resolving this issue.
    Thanks in advance .

Answer (score 0):

Can you clarify where are you getting this error. **In Sender program or the Receiver?**
This generally happens when your Sender itself fails and terminates, but your Receiver is still waits to receive connections. In such cases the above error appears in Receiver's console output, while the main exception is displayed in Sender's console.

Main exception in this case can be a security exception caused due to the case of the user not existing there (say in ApplicationRealm) or the user might not have the right roles.